# I want to limit the df1 according to the upper limit and lower limit specified in df2 with one additional conditon

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe df1 and df2. I want the output to be in range of df2 having one additional condition.
df1

```
   Value1   con1  col1
0    35    3     App1
1    30    1     App1
2    23    1     App1
3    11    3     App1
4    29    0     App1
5    13    0     App2
6    13    1     App2
7    27    0     App2
8    14    0     App2
9    10    1     App2
```

df2

```
       col1  L_limit  U_limit  condition
0      App1        20     30    1
1      App2        10    15     0
```

Required df

```
   Value1   con1  col1

1    30    1     App1
2    23    1     App1
3    13    0     App2
4    14    0     App2
```

Comment: When you say range what is it I don't see any numerical range. can you explain how did you get the required dataframe

Comment: I am referring range as L_limit and U_limit defined in df2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with filter by [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = (df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'condition':'con1'}), 
               on=['col1','con1'])
       .query("L_limit <= Value1 <= U_limit")
       .drop(['L_limit','U_limit'], axis=1))
print (df)
   Value1  con1  col1
0      30     1  App1
1      23     1  App1
2      13     0  App2
4      14     0  App2
```

EDIT: Instead `query` is possible use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'condition':'con1'}), on=['col1','con1'])
     
df = df.loc[df["Value1"].between(df["L_limit"], df["U_limit"]), ['Value1','con1','col1']]
print (df)
   Value1  con1  col1
0      30     1  App1
1      23     1  App1
2      13     0  App2
4      14     0  App2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any other way without using DataFrame.query?